# How can I migrate a website from old VPS to new VPS based on ubuntu 20:04?

Tags: 20.04, apache2

I am new in Ubuntu OS but need to learn. I have a website located on old VPS based on Ubuntu 20.04 and need to migrate all project to new VPS based on same OS:

1. First,  I push the entire website from old VPS to GITHUB
2. Second, I pull the website from GITHUB to new VPS
3. I backup the DB from old VPS, then retore it to new Server
4. I configure apache2 virtualhost
5. I disactivate the default host and activate the new domain

But, I can't no longer access the new domain even after disactivate the default domain. Noted that in the old VPS, there is the main domain and a subdomain. in order to do not get the old domain down, i decided to migrate first the subdomain to new VPS, any sense for this ?

**LOG from new VPS :**

```
ubuntu@ns3207232:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled$ ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 ubuntu root 4096 Apr  4 16:15 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 ubuntu root 4096 Mar 31 07:34 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root   48 Apr  4 08:01 preprod.ileodiamants.com.conf -> ../sites-available/preprod.ileodiamants.com.conf
ubuntu@ns3207232:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled$

ubuntu@ns3207232:/var/www/ileodiamants$ ls
preprod  prod
ubuntu@ns3207232:/var/www/ileodiamants$
```

SITES AVAILABLES

```
ubuntu@ns3207232:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ ls
000-default.conf  default-ssl.conf  preprod.ileodiamants.com.conf
ubuntu@ns3207232:/etc/apache2/sites-available$
```

```
   ServerName preprod.ileodiamants.com
   ServerAlias  preprod.mweziuwalia.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/ileodiamants/preprod

   <Directory /var/www/ileodiamants/preprod/>
      Require all granted
      AllowOverride All
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
   </Directory>
```

**LOG from old VPS :**

```
ubuntu@vps-e4382155:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled$ ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr  6 06:11 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Mar 29 12:13 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   40 Oct  3  2020 ileodiamants.com.conf -> ../sites-available/ileodiamants.com.conf
ubuntu@vps-e4382155:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled$
```

DOMAIN WWWW

```
ubuntu@vps-e4382155:/var/www$ cd ileodiamants
ubuntu@vps-e4382155:/var/www/ileodiamants$ ls
preprod  prod
ubuntu@vps-e4382155:/var/www/ileodiamants$
```

SITES AVAILABLE

```
ubuntu@vps-e4382155:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ ls
000-default.conf  default-ssl.conf  ileodiamants.com.conf  preprod.ileodiamants.com.conf
ubuntu@vps-e4382155:/etc/apache2/sites-available$
```

```
   ServerName preprod.ileodiamants.com
   ServerAlias  preprod.mweziuwalia.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/ileodiamants/preprod

   <Directory /var/www/ileodiamants/preprod/>
      Require all granted
      AllowOverride All
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
   </Directory>

   <Directory /var/www/ileodiamants/preprod/>
      Require all granted
      AllowOverride All
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
   </Directory>
```

Comment: Silly question, but did you reload Apache after enabling the site? `sudo service apache2 reload`. What do you see when you try to load the site from the new server? Is it the default Apache page or a 500 error?

Comment: @matigo, Thanks for your reply yes of course I did. When accessing the new site from new server i am redirecting to old site main domain as i disable the subdomain.

Comment: Have you updated your DNS records to point to the new server?